# Roblox lua script not working with no changes

Tags: lua, roblox

I was testing my roblox story game, I didn't change anything, it was working before. And now it just stops!

```
local CreateDialogueEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.CreateDialogueEvent
local TimerEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.TimerEvent
local EndEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.EndEvent
-- Other Useful Functions

local randomPlayerName
local randomPlayerId

local function getPlayerImage(player_id)
    local content, isReady = game:GetService("Players"):GetUserThumbnailAsync(player_id, Enum.ThumbnailType.HeadShot, Enum.ThumbnailSize.Size420x420)
    return content
end

local function getRandomPlayer()
    local players = game.Players:getPlayers()
    local number = math.random(1,#players)
    local randomPlayer = players[number]
    randomPlayerName = randomPlayer.Name
    randomPlayerId = randomPlayer.UserId
end

----------------------------------------

-- put your challenge functions here

local function challeng_example() -- THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE! IT WON'T RUN
    local teacher_Image = "rbxassetid://4841171880"
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(teacher_Image,"Hello Students!")
    wait(5)
    getRandomPlayer()
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(getPlayerImage(randomPlayerId),"I think this is the School!")
end

local function challenge_intro()
    local function checkIfPlayerSit()
        for i, v in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
            if v.Character then
                if v.Character.Humanoid.Sit ~= true then
                    v.Character.Humanoid.Health = 0
                end
            end
        end
    end
    local teacher_Image = "rbxassetid://13977347376"
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(teacher_Image,"Hey guys! You all ready for the dance?")
    wait(7)
    getRandomPlayer()
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(getPlayerImage(randomPlayerId),"Yeah!")
    wait(7)
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(teacher_Image,"Grab a seat!")
    TimerEvent:FireAllClients(20)
    wait(20)
    checkIfPlayerSit()
end

local function challenge_1()
    wait(10)
    game.Lighting.TimeOfDay = ("01:00:00")
    local teacher_Image = "rbxassetid://13977347376"
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(teacher_Image,"Hmm, seems the power went out, let me check.")
    game.Workspace["Mr Blobbellson"]:Destroy()
    game.Workspace["Glass Door"].Model.one.CanCollide = true
    game.Workspace["Glass Door"].Model.twoww.CanCollide = true
    game.Workspace["Glass Door"].Model.twee.CanCollide = true
    game.Workspace["Glass Door"].Model.fo.CanCollide = true
    game.Workspace["Glass Door"].Model.fiv.CanCollide = true
    wait(5)
    local monster = game.ReplicatedStorage.tutorialMonster:Clone()
    monster.Parent = game.Workspace
    getRandomPlayer()
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(getPlayerImage(randomPlayerId),"AHHHHH, AHHHHH, AHHHH, WHAT THE HECK, AHHH, WHAT IS THAT?")
    wait(20)
    game.Lighting.TimeOfDay = ("17:40:00")
    monster:Destroy()
end

local function challenge_2()
    local teacherclone  = game.ReplicatedStorage["Mr Blobbellson"]:Clone()
    teacherclone.Parent = game.Workspace
    local teacher_Image = "rbxassetid://13977347376"
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(teacher_Image,"Just a little power outage, you alright guys?")
    wait(9)
    getRandomPlayer()
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(getPlayerImage(randomPlayerId),"N-N-N-N-No, the-re-re was a creature.....")
    wait(6)
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(teacher_Image,"Ah, don't be ridiculous, let's go dance!")
    wait(9)
    game.Lighting.TimeOfDay = ("01:00:00")
    wait(1)
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(teacher_Image,"Hmm, I swear I just fixed those lights, let me check again.")
    teacherclone:Destroy()
    wait(3)
    local monster = game.ReplicatedStorage.tutorialMonster:Clone()
    monster.Parent = game.Workspace
    getRandomPlayer()
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(getPlayerImage(randomPlayerId),"AGAIN, WHY AGAIN THIS IS SO WEIRD HELP HELP, HELP AHHHHH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
    wait(10)
    game.Lighting.TimeOfDay = ("17:40:00")
    local teacherclone1 = game.ReplicatedStorage["Mr Blobbellson"]:Clone()
    teacherclone1.Parent = game.Workspace
    monster:Destroy()
end

local function challenge_3()
    wait(10)
    game.Lighting.TimeOfDay = ("01:00:00")
    local teacher_Image = "rbxassetid://13977347376"
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(teacher_Image,"Again! For goodness sake like.")
    
    wait(5)
    local monster1 = game.ReplicatedStorage.tutorialMonster1:Clone()
    monster1.Parent = game.Workspace
    getRandomPlayer()
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(getPlayerImage(randomPlayerId),"WHY, WHY WHY WHY! Quick, lets find the key to the bathroom!")
    local key = game.ReplicatedStorage.bathroomKey:Clone()
    key.Parent = game.Workspace
    repeat wait(0.1) until game.Workspace:FindFirstChild("bathroomKey") == nil
    getRandomPlayer()
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(getPlayerImage(randomPlayerId),"Phew, we found the key! Quick, get to the bathroom!")
    game.Workspace.InvisibleBathroomWall.Transparency = 1
    game.Workspace.InvisibleBathroomWall.CanCollide = false
    wait(20)
    game.Workspace.InvisibleBathroomWall.CanCollide = true
    game.Workspace.InvisibleBathroomWall.Transparency = 0
    monster1:Destroy()
end


local function challenge_ending()
    local teacher_Image = "rbxassetid://13977347376"
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(teacher_Image,"Students?! Students?! I have something to tell you!")
    wait(10)
    local knife = game.ReplicatedStorage.KNIFE:Clone()
    knife.Parent = game.Workspace
    local teacher = game.ReplicatedStorage["Mr Blobbellson2"]:Clone()
    teacher.Parent = game.Workspace
    local chairSeat = game.ReplicatedStorage["Chair not really by ULTRApizzaland"]:Clone()
    chairSeat.Parent = game.Workspace
    game.Workspace.chairSeat.Seat:Sit(teacher.Humanoid)
    getRandomPlayer()
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(getPlayerImage(randomPlayerId),"Should we get out?")
    wait(5)
    getRandomPlayer()
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(getPlayerImage(randomPlayerId),"Yeah.")
    game.Workspace.InvisibleBathroomWall.CanCollide = false
    game.Workspace.InvisibleBathroomWall.Transparency = 1
    wait(5)
    getRandomPlayer()
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(getPlayerImage(randomPlayerId),"Ummmmmm, teacher, what's that on the ground?")
    wait(7)
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(teacher_Image,"Nothing...")
    wait(7)
    getRandomPlayer()
    CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(getPlayerImage(randomPlayerId), "We have to decide if we trust him or not.")
    TimerEvent:FireAllClients(15)
    wait(15)
    if game.Workspace:FindFirstChild("KNIFE") then 
        getRandomPlayer()
        CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(getPlayerImage(randomPlayerId), "K, we trust you.")
        CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(teacher_Image,"Haha, fools, I'm the monster!")
        wait(5)
        EndEvent:FireAllClients()
    else
        getRandomPlayer()
        CreateDialogueEvent:FireAllClients(getPlayerImage(randomPlayerId), "We know you're the monster! We're gonna have to kill you!")
        wait(5)
        EndEvent:FireAllClients()
    end
end

--------------------------------------------------

local function startGame() -- This is your main function where we order the challenges
    challenge_intro()
    challenge_1()
    challenge_2()
    challenge_3()
    challenge_ending()
end

wait(3) -- waits 3 seconds
startGame() -- runs the startGame function
```

Comment: Heyo, more information would be really helpful. Where does it stop? Does it always stop in the same place? Are any messages appearing in the Output widget?

Comment: No messages in the output widget. It stops at the: Students?! Students?! I have something to tell you! The stuff spawns in but then no more dialogue, it doesn't open the door, all in all, very weird!

Comment: I fixed it, I made a new script, disabled it, wrote the code in it, enabled it after a certain amount of time, published it to roblox! (Also the game is https://web.roblox.com/games/13989155254/Dance-Story)